# Advanced rdlc report design

Tags: c#, rdlc

I made an application in C# Visual Studio 2010 that generates reports about the work that my clients employees do. The application does everything that is requested, but my client additionally requested the data shown in reports should be grouped by the employee who performed it (each employee and the work he's done is represented by a database entry). Let me clarify this request:

A report about a single employee contains a header with his name, last name, serial number and then the report data contains time he got to/off work and some other information. Now that is done just fine, my client accepted that part of the solution, but how can I make the general report (for all employees) that would display all the data in the database but divided into sections (it should look like all the individual reports got pasted on the same report) so that when the general report is viewed, the viewer can still see who did what (in the general report the workers are represented by their serial number, not by their name). I have no idea how to do this, so please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a parameter to your data procedure which takes EmployeeID, (or whatever it is in your case), if the input parameter is null return all employees, else, return the record matching the input param.

You should set your report to "page break" after each record.

This is going to be off the top of my head as the machine I am on is not configured with SSRS.

Could you not just set the border colours of your "report grouping" then configure the data table to "page break after group", (right-click "Tablix Properties"?

Comment: No, the returning is not the problem, the report displays the data correctly, my problem is of pure aesthetic nature. I already set the sorting parameters, so that report displays the data ordered by the employee, but how can I make a "box" that would envelop all the entries by one employee so that it is easy to spot where the transition between two employees is (it sounds banal, but when you have 100 entries for one employee, and then only 2-3 entries for another, it is a bit hard to spot where the transition occurred)

Comment: I tried with Tablix Properties, it didn't work, but then I tried with grouping by row, and adding "break after group" to that, and it is working satisfactorily for now -I'll try to polish it up a bit, and see if it satisfies my client's needs. Thanks for your answer.